# Changing UILabel text has delay, but why?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

in my app I want to set the text of an `UILabel`. The text comes from a JSON-object. I add my `UILabel` to my storyboard, set the `IBOutlet` and call my async-method to get my JSON-object.
In the response-method I set the text of the `UILabel`. But the text change needs some seconds. 
When the response comes I print it to the console. There I can see, that the delay doesnt comes from the async-method.
The response comes, I can see it in the console. Wait some seconds than the `UIlabel` changes.
I dont understand this behaviour, is there a trick to refresh the `UIlabel` instantly?

some code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label_news: UILabel!;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label_news.text = "CHANGE";
    rcall.GetNews_GET_NewsResponse_0(self.NewsResponseHandler);
}

func NewsResponseHandler(resp:NewsResponse!){
    self.label_news.text = resp.NewsText;
    println(resp.NewsText);
}
```

Sorry if this is a beginner question, swift and storyboards are totally new for me.

best regards

Comment: Because that response handler is probably not getting called on the main thread. Dispatch it back to the main queue. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) { ... }`

Comment: Works great thanks. Answer down is marked as solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like what Rob stated in the comment, all UI changes need to be done on the main thread. I haven't implemented it in Swift yet, but the Objective-C and what I'm assuming would be the Swift is below...

Objective-C

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.label_news.text = resp.NewsText;
});
```

Swift:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.label_news.text = resp.NewsText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

c_rath's answer is correct. In swift 3 the syntax was changed (yet again) to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self. label_news?.text = resp.NewsText
}
```